# Lossless compression run length encoding in javascript

Tags: javascript, lossless-compression

## For my assignment, I am writing the code to compress and then decompress a string through lossless compression in javascript.

For example- 
Original string: heeeeelllllloo 
Compressed: h1e5l6o2 
Decompressed: heeeeelllllloo

This code comes out as an infinite loop, and the problem is somewhere in the compression function. Please help me find/solve the issue! 
This is what I have so far:

```
// Read in the original text
var textToCompress = prompt("Enter the text you would like to compress: ");
runLengthEncoding(textToCompress);

function runLengthEncoding(originalText){
console.log("Original Text: " + originalText);
console.log("");

// Compress the text
console.log("COMPRESSING...");

var compressedText = compress(originalText);
console.log("Compressed: " + compressedText);
console.log("");

//Decompress the text
console.log("DECOMPRESSING...");

//var decompressedText = decompress(compressedText);
console.log("Decompressed: " + decompressedText);
console.log("");

// Make sure the compression was lossless
if(originalText == decompressedText)
{
    console.log("Success! The decompressed text is the same as the original!");
}
}

// Compresses the original String by building up a new String
// with each character and how many times it repeats in a given run.
// Returns the compressed text.
function compress(original){
  var result = "";
  //Write your code here
  for (var i = 1; i < original.length; i++){//look at each character in string
    var sum = 1;
    var currentChar = original.charAt(i);
    //if currentchar is the first character
    if (currentChar == original.charAt(0)){//isolate frist character of the string
      result = currentChar;//add the currentchar to result
      console.log(result);
    //if currentchar is not the first character
    } else if (currentChar !== original.charAt(0)) {
      //if currentchar is equal to the previous character
      if (currentChar == original.charAt(i-1)){
        sum++;
    } else {
        result += sum;//add sum ot the result and reset sum to 1
        sum = 1;
        i = 0;
      }

}
}
}

// Decompresses the compressed Run Length Encoded text back
// into the original form.
function decompress(compressedText)
{
var result = "";

for(var i = 0; i < compressedText.length; i += 2)
{
    // Get the current run character
    var character = compressedText.charAt(i);

    // Get the run length
    var runLength = parseInt(compressedText.charAt(i+1));

    // Add that many repetitions of the original character to the result
    for(var runIndex = 0; runIndex < runLength; runIndex++)
    {
        result += character;
    }
}

return result;
}
```

Comment: Ok, and your question is?

Comment: This is not a compression, this is in most cases an inflation. This first sentence would encode as: `T1h1i1s1 1i1s1 1n1o1t1 a1 1c1o1m1p1r1e1s2i1o1n1,1 1t1h1i1s1 1i1s1 1i1n1 1m1o1s1t1 1c1a1s1e1s1 1a1n1 1i1n1f1l1a1t1i1o1n1.1` Is that _really_ what you want?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't compare the chars to find out if this char is the first one, because this would return true if the first char is repeated in the text.

The seond thing I saw, is that you set the index i to 0 every time you find a new character which leads your function to start at the beginning of the string again and will end in a deadlock.

Thats at least what I think, and I hope I could help you